# Switching R version in RStudio temporarily

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

Sometimes I need to use older version of R in RStudio but I don't want to downgrade R permanently. RStudio for Windows offers a comfortable tool for switching R versions. It is sufficient to open Tools > Global Options > General and switch R version as shown in the picture. But it is not available in RStudio for Linux. I would appreciate some easy and fast method for switching R version, not upgrading/downgrading.

Thanks in advance for answers.

[image]

Comment: Hey check https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop      under linux desktop. might help

Comment: export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R